# LINQ to DataSet to get generic list from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

```
DataTable table = DataProvider.GetTable()

var clientIds = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
                select r.Field<string>("CLIENT_ID");
```

I want `clientIds` to be a `List<string>`.  Currently it's an `EnumerableRowCollection<>`

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may work

```
DataTable table = DataProvider.GetTable()

var clientIds = (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
                select r.Field<string>("CLIENT_ID")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var clientIds = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.Field<string>("CLIENT_ID").ToList();
```

Or, if this syntax is working but not bringing back the results as a list, you can do something like:

```
var clientIds = (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
                select r.Field<string>("CLIENT_ID")).ToList();
```